# Distance between points to points in QGIS

Tags: point, distance

I have two points layer one has some 70,000 points (Layer A) and other has some 5000 points( Layer B). I want to calculate distance of Layer A points to Layer B Points. But unfortunately both don't have any common ID.

Comment: Well, then how do you know which points needs to be connected to which others?

Comment: @Erik well there are two IDs one is Event id in Layer A , and Cell ID in Layer B. Based on Event id of  layer A I want to calculate distance of all cell id of Layer B. i.e. suppose Event ID is 1 of layer A and Cell ids of layer B are A, B,C, D, E etc. so need to calculate distance from Event Id 1 to Cell Ids A, B,C, D, E etc.

Comment: You could dissolve layer A based on the event ID, and then calculate the distance from the multi-points to the cell IDs of layer B.

Comment: so you need distance from every point in A to all points in B? Like a distance matrix? https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoranalysis.html?highlight=distance%20matrix#distance-matrix